# What is the simplest method to parse HTML, strip scripts and return serialized HTML using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

This is my best attempt, but it is more complex than I expected it to be.

```
export function removeScripts(serializedSvg: string): string {
  const doc = $.parseHTML(serializedSvg);
  const newSerialized = doc.reduce((str, el) => {
    return $(el).prop("outerHTML") as string;
  }, "");
  return newSerialized;
}
```

Are there perhaps other exposed methods that allow me to achieve the same end goal without having to loop over an array?

Comment: Does your current code work? Are you looking to strip out `<script>` tags specifically somehow? I don't get the purpose of the `outerHTML`

Comment: Your current code doesn't seem overly complex to me (other than that `$(el).prop("outerHTML")` is a long way to write `el.outerHTML`). But it also doesn't seem to strip out `script` elements.

Comment: @CertainPerformance: It works. I just don't know any other method than outerHTML for getting html serialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't seem overly complex to me (other than that `$(el).prop("outerHTML")` is a long way to write `el.outerHTML`). But it also doesn't seem to strip out `script` elements.

This code should, see comments:

```
export function removeScripts(serializedSvg: string): string {
  // Create a wrapper for the parsed content
  const div = $("<div/>");
  // Parse it and put it in the wrapper
  div.append($.parseHTML(serializedSvg));
  // Remove scripts
  div.find("script").remove();
  // Return the result
  return div.innerHTML;
}
```